# MAC verification failure during decryption using C# AES encryption

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, cryptography

I am facing an issue with the encryption and decryption process in my C# application using AES encryption with MAC verification. The encryption seems to work fine, but when I attempt to decrypt the data, I encounter a "MAC verification failed. Data integrity compromised" error.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace HellsgateDeveloperManager
{
    public static class EncryptionManager
    {
        private const string encryptionKey = "MyEncryptionKey";

        public static byte[] EncryptWithIntegrity(string plaintext)
        {
            byte[] iv = GenerateRandomBytes(16);
            byte[] plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);

            // Calculate the MAC over the plaintext data
            byte[] mac = CalculateMAC(plaintextBytes, encryptionKey);

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
                aesAlg.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                byte[] encryptedData;
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        csEncrypt.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length);
                    }
                    encryptedData = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }

                byte[] encryptedDataWithMAC = new byte[iv.Length + encryptedData.Length + mac.Length];
                
                Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, encryptedDataWithMAC, 0, iv.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, 0, encryptedDataWithMAC, iv.Length, encryptedData.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(mac, 0, encryptedDataWithMAC, iv.Length + encryptedData.Length, mac.Length);

                return encryptedDataWithMAC;
            }
        }

        public static string DecryptWithIntegrity(byte[] encryptedDataWithMAC)
        {
            int ivLength = 16;
            int macLength = 32;
            int expectedMinLength = ivLength + macLength;

            if (encryptedDataWithMAC == null || encryptedDataWithMAC.Length < expectedMinLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid encrypted data format.");
            }

            byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
            byte[] encryptedData = new byte[encryptedDataWithMAC.Length - ivLength - macLength];
            byte[] receivedMAC = new byte[macLength];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedDataWithMAC, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedDataWithMAC, iv.Length, encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedDataWithMAC, iv.Length + encryptedData.Length, receivedMAC, 0, receivedMAC.Length);

            byte[] calculatedMAC = CalculateMAC(encryptedData, encryptionKey);

            if (!CompareMACs(receivedMAC, calculatedMAC))
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("MAC verification failed. Data integrity compromised.");
            }

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);
                aesAlg.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static byte[] CalculateMAC(byte[] data, string key)
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
            {
                return hmac.ComputeHash(data);
            }
        }

        private static bool CompareMACs(byte[] mac1, byte[] mac2)
        {
            if (mac1.Length != mac2.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mac1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (mac1[i] != mac2[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int length)
        {
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
            using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
            }
            return randomBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

The error comes whenever I try to compare MACs.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions to help me resolve this issue. If anyone has experienced a similar problem with C# AES encryption and MAC verification, or if there are any additional troubleshooting steps I can take, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!

To debug the issue, I have carefully reviewed the encryption code, including the generation of IV, and MAC. I have also checked that the same key is used for both encryption and decryption. I implemented extensive logging to track the data and key during the process, but I have not been able to identify any discrepancies. I tried using Chat-gpt for some directions but with no further help.

Comment: The iv has to be the same for encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: @jdweng That's apparent in the code though. The IV is placed in front of the ciphertext, not randomly generated during decryption.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the MAC over the plaintext for the encryption, and you are calculating the MAC *over the ciphertext* for decryption. It's probably best to convert to use [encrypt-then-mac](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/1172). That's basically what you do during decryption. If you do you should however be sure to include the IV into the calculations.

As it stands you should know that sending identical messages will result in the same MAC during encryption, which means that a small amount of information about the messages will be leaked. Worse, you're probably vulnerable against padding oracle attacks during decryption.

There are other security issues, such as using strings to constitute keys, using static methods that rely on a static key, a non-time constant compare for the authentication tag (MAC result). Maybe you can use GCM instead so that most of these issues can be easily resolved.

Even then you should probably worry if your protocol is secure and not vulnerable against e.g. replay attacks. This is why, preferably, you should not try to create your own.